# Уместность местоимений вместо имени

Tags: этикет

В некоторых языках, например, в японском, вообще стараются избегать заменять чем-то имя человека в беседе и за глаза (даже "вы-ты" редко употребляют). А насколько вообще уместны местоимения вместо имени (речь не идет о книжном тексте)?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

По правилам речевого этикета, нежелательно употреблять местоимение 3 лица, говоря о присутствующем человеке. В таком случае рекомендуется употреблять его имя собственное, а во избежание многократного повторения имени можно использовать синонимичные конструкции, в том числе описательные, например называть его по занимаемой должности, по степени близости (наш друг, наш общий знакомый и т.п.). Что касается фразы в одном из ответов, что местоимение - это то, что используется вместо имени, то позволю себе напомнить, что "вместо имени" обозначает отнюдь не только вместо имени собственного, а вместо имени существительного, имени прилагательного и имени числительного. Это азы морфологии.

Comment: Для чего существуют правила этикета? Я считаю, для того, чтобы не оскорблять собеседника, исключать из своей речи негативное воздействие на его сознание, поэтому я ими и руководствуюсь. И не вижу ничего зазорного в том, чтобы иногда в своей речи употреблять местоимения вместо имён, в том числе и при обращении к собеседнику, например: «Вы не могли бы посвятить меня в азы морфологии?» Либо же: «Виктор – вы для меня великий учитель, образованнейший человек, наимудрейший из всех мудрецов!» В последнем примере семантика синонимичных конструкций без «вы» сильно поменяется.

Comment: Иногда употребление личных местоимений уместно, но я ведь писал  не об обращении к собеседнику, а о тех случаях, когда     рассказывается о каких-то событиях. в которых участвовало третье лицо. Вот это третье лицо и  не должно заменяться местоимением третьего лица единственного числа. Примеры же, приведенные Вами, относятся к употреблению местоимений 2 лица, и здесь возражений не может быть. Особенно резко звучит "он" вместо имени или описательной конструкции, когда речь идет о присутствующем при разговоре  человеке. Неоднократно повторенное "он" в данной ситуации режет слух

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, достаточно уместно. Представьте ситуацию, в которой вам приходится донести до собеседника достаточно много информации об одном человеке, если вы не будете пользоваться местоимением, ваш собеседник устанет от многократного повторения одного слова. К тому же местоимение – вместо имени! Для того и создано. А в некоторых случаях принято употреблять только местоимения: "Сегодня Сам приезжает! — Кто? — Он!"

Comment: Действительно, неоднократные повторы  имени собственного будут резать слух, но я в своем ответе уже писал, что вместо повторения собственного имени объекта речи может быть использована описательная конструкция. Например: "Вчера к нам в гости приходил N. Мы были рады видеть друга детства. Приятель рассказал нам о своей поездке в Москву. Наш бывший одноклассник с восторгом рассказывал о своих интересных встречах в столице. Мы были рады, что нашему знакомому поездка понравилась". Полагаю, что можно в конце этой конструкции однократно употребить  "он". Это, по-моему, не будет резать слух